# Create "inner" and "outer" parbox

Tags: parbox

Is there a way to automate the mirroring of parboxes every time a new page occurs?

I have a `\documentclass{book}` that consists of two side-by-side `\parbox`. I would like one of the `\parbox` to always remain the "outer" and the other to always remain the "inner". The pages should essentially mirror each other.

**In this example, I would like the skinny column to always be the inner column:**
[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\parbox[t][][t]{.7\linewidth}{\lipsum[1]}\hfill
\parbox[t][][t]{.25\linewidth}{\lipsum[2]}

\noindent
\parbox[t][][t]{.7\linewidth}{\lipsum[8]}\hfill
\parbox[t][][t]{.25\linewidth}{\lipsum[9]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does your document *only* contain these `\parbox`es? Do you *always* insert these the same way? Is there any flow from one page to the next?

Comment: You can also do this using paracol.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320065/marginpar-start-at-top-of-page/320077?s=5|0.0456#320077 for example.

Comment: @Werner, yes, let's assume that the document contains only the `\parbox`es, the content within them will be of different lengths, and there is flow from one page to the next.

Comment: @John, do you think `paracol` is a better solution here? Would you please propose an example solution?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I figured out what you meant: `\twosided[pc]% swap margins and columns` under `\usepackage{paracol}`. Does anyone know how to achieve the same thing but with `\parbox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\parbox` macros are optional.  Their only effect here is to force a `\newpage` if there is not enough space for the whole thing.  Alignment is handled by `\switchcolumn*`.  (Without the `\parbox` you should use `\sloppy`.)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}

\setcolumnwidth{.7\textwidth,.25\textwidth}
\columnsep=.05\textwidth
\twosided[pc]% swap margins and columns

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\noindent\parbox{\columnwidth}{\lipsum[1]}
\switchcolumn
\noindent\parbox{\columnwidth}{\lipsum[2]}
\switchcolumn*
\noindent\parbox{\columnwidth}{\lipsum[8]}
\switchcolumn
\noindent\parbox{\columnwidth}{\lipsum[9]}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

---

Here is a solution using the ifoddpage package.  It takes two runs, since `\checkoddpage` stores the page number in the aux file.  The `\makebox` is used to force the page change before testing.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\newcommand{\swapboxes}[2]% #1 = wide text, #2 = narrow text
{\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\checkoddpage
 \ifoddpageoroneside
   \parbox[t]{.7\textwidth}{#1}\hfill\parbox[t]{.25\textwidth}{#2}%
 \else
   \parbox[t]{.25\textwidth}{#2}\hfill\parbox[t]{.7\textwidth}{#1}%
 \fi}}

\begin{document}

\swapboxes{\lipsum[1]}{\lipsum[2]}

\swapboxes{\lipsum[8]}{\lipsum[9]}

\end{document}
```