# Inconsistent paragraph spacing with \parbox for custom design

Tags: margins, minipage, book-design, parbox, baseline

I am working on a project that requires generating latex code programmatically from a JSON file, which contains a transcribed conversation. The design of the final goal is non-standard. It requires that the two subjects involved intercalate their answers similar to a script, as in the attached example. The difficulty I'm running into is that I cannot find a satisfactory solution to achieve that design, since a \minipage or a \parbox approach seem to result in inconsistency paragraph spacings (see for instance the second page left paragraphs in the attached images)

[image]
[image]

I may be doing this in a wrong way, but since the source data is quite large and the LaTeX code needs to be generated I cannot have a single minipage for instance for all text on the left and another for the right since the input can be unknown (fetched on the fly from a website).

It seems that I am forced to create a parbox for every text input which then needs to be placed on the left or right of the page, as in the following code example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[ 
paperwidth = 280mm, 
paperheight = 220mm,
layouthoffset = 3mm, 
layoutvoffset = 3mm,
top = 16mm,
bottom = 31mm,
left = 19mm,
right = 19mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\newcommand\msgL[2]{
    \reversemarginpar \marginnote{\emph{\textsuperscript{#2}}}
    \raggedright \parbox{9.6cm}{#1} \par
}

\newcommand\msgR[2]{
    \normalmarginpar \marginnote{\emph{\textsuperscript{#2}}}
    \raggedleft \parbox{9.6cm}{\raggedleft #1} \par
}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{12pt}{15pt}\selectfont

\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore}{Name1} 
\msgR{Lorem ipsum}{Name2}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}{}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}{}
\msgL{Lorem}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}{}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor}{}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet. Turpis massa sed}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}{}
\msgL{\textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor}{}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor}{}
\msgL{\textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, }{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, }{}
\msgL{\textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor}{}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi. Ut tellus elementum}{}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod}{}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}{}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit}{}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt}{}
\msgR{Lorem}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}{}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}{}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit}{}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna}{}
\msgR{Lorem}{}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum}{}
\msgR{\textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}}{}

\end{document}
```

It would be great to know if there is a proper way to achieve this that can scale up for a large amount of input data under the conditions described. Many thanks!

Comment: There may be a better way to avoid the problem of the `\parbox`es being smashed together, but the reason for that is the absence of anything at the beginning (height) and end (descender depth) of the `\parbox` contents to ensure maintenance of the regular `\baselineskip`.  If you add a `\strut` at the beginning and end of the data in the `\parbox, that will ensure a height and depth in the first and last line so that adjacent `\parbox`es will be properly separated.

Comment: @barbarabeeton This was my first attempt. It gets better, but the boxes are still too close, less than `\baselineskip`.

Comment: @gernot -- I see that the type size has been set to 12pt on a 15pt baseline.  The default `\strut` is almost certainly not set to extend to 15pt, and unless `\selectfont` resets it (I don't know and haven't checked), either `\strut` would need to be redefined, or a new one defined, say `\strutxv`.  Then it's a matter of determining how to split that 15pt between height and depth (which I haven't done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas that might help.

- The package `paracol` is for typesetting material in columns and for switching back and forth between the columns. You can also typeset one or both columns justified.
- You could make the name an optional argument. Not sure whether this makes life easier when creating the conversation automatically.
- In case the margin notes cause problems, you can use ordinary boxes. On the left-hand side, start the text with

  ```
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\scriptsize\emph{#1}\quad}
  ```

  on the right-hand side with

  ```
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\quad\scriptsize\emph{#1}}\\[-\baselineskip]
  ```

The relevant definitions in the code below are:

```
\usepackage{paracol}

\newenvironment{conversation}{%
  \begin{paracol}{2}
    \fontsize{12pt}{15pt}\selectfont
}{%
  \end{paracol}
}

\newcommand\msgL[2][]{%
  \begin{leftcolumn*}\raggedright
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\scriptsize\emph{#1}\quad}#2
  \end{leftcolumn*}
}

\newcommand\msgR[2][]{%
  \begin{rightcolumn*}\raggedleft
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\quad\scriptsize\emph{#1}}\\[-\baselineskip]
    #2
  \end{rightcolumn*}
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[ 
paperwidth = 280mm, 
paperheight = 220mm,
layouthoffset = 3mm, 
layoutvoffset = 3mm,
top = 16mm,
bottom = 31mm,
left = 19mm,
right = 19mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{paracol}

\newenvironment{conversation}{%
  \begin{paracol}{2}
    \fontsize{12pt}{15pt}\selectfont
}{%
  \end{paracol}
}

\newcommand\msgL[2][]{%
  \begin{leftcolumn*}\raggedright
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\scriptsize\emph{#1}\quad}#2
  \end{leftcolumn*}
}

\newcommand\msgR[2][]{%
  \begin{rightcolumn*}\raggedleft
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\quad\scriptsize\emph{#1}}\\[-\baselineskip]
    #2
  \end{rightcolumn*}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{conversation}
\msgL[Name1]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore}
\msgR[Name2]{Lorem ipsum}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}
\msgL{Lorem}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet. Turpis massa sed}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}
\msgL{\textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor}
\msgL{\textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, }
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, }
\msgL{\textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi. Ut tellus elementum}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt}
\msgR{Lorem}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit}
\msgL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna}
\msgR{Lorem}
\msgR{Lorem ipsum}
\msgR{\textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}}
\end{conversation}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** In the comments, John Kormylo proposes to typeset the margin notes in two further columns, like he explains in [his answer to "\marginpar start at top of page"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320077/110998). With this approach, the `paracol` packages manages two narrow and two wider columns, defined e.g. like this.

```
\usepackage{paracol}
\columnratio{0.1,0.4,0.4,0.1}

\newenvironment{conversation}{%
  \begin{paracol}{4}
    \fontsize{12pt}{15pt}\selectfont
}{%
  \end{paracol}
}

\newcommand\msgL[2][]{%
  \begin{nthcolumn*}{1}\raggedright#2\end{nthcolumn*}
  \begin{nthcolumn}{0}\raggedleft\scriptsize\emph{#1}\quad\end{nthcolumn}
}

\newcommand\msgR[2][]{%
  \begin{nthcolumn*}{2}\raggedleft#2\end{nthcolumn*}
  \begin{nthcolumn}{3}\raggedright\scriptsize\emph{#1}\quad\end{nthcolumn}
}
```

Comment: Another way to do margin notes is to use 4 columns instead of 2.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320065/marginpar-start-at-top-of-page/320077?r=SearchResults&s=1|28.1390#320077

Comment: @JohnKormylo That's an interesting way to view margin notes. Do you want to post a solution illustrating it, or should I edit mine?

Comment: Up to you.  Once was enough for me.

Comment: Fantastic, a perfectly apt solution for what I needed. Many thanks @gernot